# PosgreSQL INSERT ON CONFLICT sometimes does not work with partial index

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
    type character varying,
    id   integer
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS uniq_id_test 
    ON test USING btree (type, id) 
    WHERE (type = 'Test');

PREPARE test (text, int, text) AS
    INSERT INTO test (type, id)
    VALUES ($1, $2)
    ON CONFLICT (type, id)
    WHERE type = $3 DO
    UPDATE
    SET id = EXCLUDED.id;


EXECUTE test('Test', 1, 'Test');
EXECUTE test('Test', 2, 'Test');
EXECUTE test('Test', 3, 'Test');
EXECUTE test('Test', 4, 'Test');
EXECUTE test('Test', 5, 'Test');
EXECUTE test('Test', 6, 'Test');
```

The last `EXECUTE` statement always throws an error:

> [42P10] ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

If we `DEALLOCATE` the prepared statement and then re-create it, we will have another 5 successful attempts and on the 6th attempt we again will get the error above.

All of it works fine if we replace `$3` parameter with a constant value `'Test'` (no errors):

```sql
PREPARE test (text, int, text) AS
    INSERT INTO test (type, id)
    VALUES ($1, $2)
    ON CONFLICT (type, id)
    WHERE type = 'Test' DO
    UPDATE
    SET id = EXCLUDED.id;
```

So, according to this, I can suppose that the root cause is that I used a parameter instead of a constant in `INSERT ON CONFLICT WHERE` prepared statement, and plancacher or smth works incorrectly with it. But I would like to see a more detailed explanation of the problem above because I'm not a DB specialist and don't get why it works in this way...

PG Version:

```
PostgreSQL 13.9 (Debian 13.9-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, 
compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
```

Comment: I'm going to say it is due to: *. The current rule for this is that the first five executions are done with custom plans and the average estimated cost of those plans is calculated. Then a generic plan is created and its estimated cost is compared to the average custom-plan cost. Subsequent executions use the generic plan if its cost is not so much higher than the average custom-plan cost as to make repeated replanning seem preferable.* from here [Prepare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html).

Comment: Isn't it considered a bug if the generic plan leads to the situation when the query is broken?

Comment: First establish that is the problem. See the *Notes* section of the `Prepare` link I posted earlier on how to force a generic or custom plan. If it is a problem I would suggest either file of bug report here [Bug](https://www.postgresql.org/account/login/?next=/account/submitbug/) *Note you will need a community account* or ask on the `pgsql-general` mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

That is because from the sixth execution on, PostgreSQL uses a *generic plan* for this prepared statement. Such a generic plan doesn't use the parameter values. The idea behind that is to avoid the effort of re-planning the statement for every execution. As a consequence, the value of `$3` is not known, and the partial index cannot be inferred.

You may make a case that this is a bug on the mailing list, but I doubt that it will be accepted as such.

The workaround you can use is to avoid generic plans by setting `plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan`.